# Write long netCDF attribute using python

Tags: python, attributes, netcdf4

I am trying to write a netCDF files which one of the attributes is a long description of what it is in that files.

Assuming that start with:

`ds = nc.Dataset(filename, 'w', format='NETCDF4')`

then the attribute would be:

`ds.Data_Attribution = "This netCDF files contains all the data recovered from different sources: Source one: Description and url  Source one: Description and url "`

And I would like to have each source in a different line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do something like:

```
ds.Data_Attribution = "This netCDF files contains all the data recovered from different sources"
ds.Source1 = "Description and url  Source one: Description and url"
ds.Source2 = "Description and url  Source two: Description and url"
```

You can also try `xarray` to work with netcdf files. It reads netcdf files as "xarray dataarray", then it can also save out as netcdf files very easily. And it can generate very neat attributes like below:

```
import xarray as xr

# create a sample xarray data array
ds = xr.Dataset({'var': [1, 2,3,4,5]})

# edit attributes
ds.attrs['Short name']  = "a short name"
ds.attrs['Long name']   = "a long name"
ds.attrs['Description'] = "full description"

# check the results
display(ds)

# save out as a netcdf file
ds.to_netcdf("my_netcdffile.nc")
```